# how can I make the code play a file on my computer?

Tags: swf

var SWF_PLAYER_URL = 'http://beworld.perso.sfr.fr/bao/miniplayer.swf';
var SWF_ALARM_URL = "http://gamespowerita.com/Tools/GoR/Plugins/Allarmi/alarmplayer.swf";

I'm not sure if this is enough info but I would like the swf player to play a file from my computer when triggered. The swf_alarm_url above appear to no longer work. how can I make the code play a file on my computer??

Answer (score 0):

Try using the path to the file on your computer.

For example:

var SWF_PLAYER_URL = 'c:\Users\yourusername\music\yourmusicfile.swf';

Comment: didn't work. perhaps I need to find a way to post the entire code

Comment: Try playing around with it a bit, use " instead of '

Comment: Also your question is very vauge, you don't mention to language you are using.